# Getting error when embedding mongoose in Angular 2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I have added mongoose via:

```
npm install mongoose --save

npm install @types/mongoose --save
```

and I have the systemjs.config.js file:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',
            //etc...
            'mongoose': 'npm:mongoose'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            //etc...
            mongoose: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

but I'm getting this 404 error:
404 GET /node_modules/mongoose/
and this is the console log error:

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/mongoose/(…)
Please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: you added the typings (typescript definitions) for mongoose, but you didn't add mongoose itself ( npm install mongoose --save )

Comment: I have added mongoose also.  @lexith

Comment: Are you able to retreive other modules from ./node_modules/ ?

Comment: yes I am able to GET another module the only problem is with mongoose @Lazyexpert